# Using Scanned-In Variables to Initialize an Integer Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, int, scanf

I'm trying to initialize an integer array with variables that have scanned in values in C. The values in the array do not match what I scanned in.  It stores weird numbers like -1040000000 or 37299 in the array instead.
Any help would be much appreciated, I'm pretty new to programming!

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;

int intarr[3] = {num1, num2, num3};

printf("Enter 3 numbers.\n");
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
scanf("%d", &num3);
```

There are no error messages, but the numbers aren't what I inputted. For example, I scanned in numbers 1, 2, 3. And when I printed out the values at each index of my array, it printed out weird numbers like I stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` to initialize the array before you fill in the variables with `scanf()`. You have to scan into the variables first, then assign them to the array.

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;

printf("Enter 3 numbers.\n");
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
scanf("%d", &num3);

int intarr[3] = {num1, num2, num3};
```

You should enable full warnings from your compiler, it probably would have warned that you were using variables before initializing them. See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

You could also skip the variables entirely, and just scan directly into the array.

```
printf("Enter 3 numbers.\n");
int intarr[3];
scanf("%d", &intarr[0]);
scanf("%d", &intarr[1]);
scanf("%d", &intarr[2]);
```

Comment: Or `if (scanf("%d%d%d", &intarr[0], &intarr[1], &intarr[2]) != 3) { …oops!… }`, using one call to read all three values, and checking that all three are read successfully.  Using separate inputs, you should use something like: `if (scanf("%d", &intarr[0]) == 1 &&
scanf("%d", &intarr[1]) == 1 &&
scanf("%d", &intarr[2]) == 1) { …three values read OK… } else { …at least failed… }`.  Or use a `for` loop to read one value at a time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, there are lots of ways to do it better, but this isn't [codereview.se]. So I kept it similar to the original code.